# Почему работа метода начинается с непустым массивом matr у объекта res?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import functools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from math import *
import random

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,rows=0,cols=0,matr=[]):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.matr = matr

    def __add__(self,m):

        if (self.rows != m.rows or self.cols != m.cols):
            return "Wrong size"

        res = Matrix(self.rows,self.cols,[])
        for i in range(self.rows):
            res.matr.append(list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,self.matr[i],m.matr[i])))

        return res

    def __mul__(self,m):
        if isinstance(m,int):
            result = Matrix(self.rows,self.cols,[])
            for i in range(self.row):
                result.matr.append(list(map(lambda x: m*x, self.matr[i]))   )

        elif isinstance(m,Matrix):
            if (self.cols != m.rows):
                return "Wrong size"

            res = Matrix(self.rows,m.cols,[])
            for i in range(self.rows):
                tmp=[]
                for j in range(m.cols):
                    c=0
                    for k in range(self.cols):
                        c+=(self.matr[i][k]*m.matr[k][j])
                    tmp.append(c)
                res.matr.append(tmp)
            return res
```

Суть вопроса в следующем: при работе методов сложения/умножения, если явно не указывать при создании res (внутри этих методов), что res.matr = [] (это указывается явно при вызове конструктора), то при проведении нескольких операций сложения/умножения при очередном использовании одного из операторов res.matr будет совсем не пустым, в нем будет результат предыдущего вызова. Если указывать явно в конструкторе, то проблема решается (так это сделано в коде ниже). Вопрос: почему так? Ведь по умолчанию указано, что matr = [].

Comment: Пример последовательности вызовов добавите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На подобные вопросы много раз тут отвечали. Дело в том, что в питоне параметры по умолчанию работают не так, как в других языках. Определения функций и методов отрабатывают один раз - когда интерпретатор читает определение функции/метода. Именно тогда выставляются параметры по умолчанию. При вызове функций/методов они уже не выставляются. Поэтому в питоне не рекомендуется использовать коллекции в качестве параметров по умолчанию - они не сбрасываются в начальное состояние, а переиспользуются, что вы и наблюдаете. Обходится это заданием `None` в качестве параметра по умолчанию и последующей проверкой на это значение. Например, так в вашем случае:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,rows=0,cols=0,matr=None):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        if matr is None:
            self.matr = []
        else:
            self.matr = matr
```

Можно сделать этот `if` в одну строку с помощью *тернарного оператора*:

```
        self.matr = [] if matr is None else matr
```

Или совсем коротко, пользуясь знаниями о булевых значениях пустых объектов и `None` и не пустых объектов:

```
        self.matr = matr or []
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, теперь стало понятно, в чем проблема ^_^